# Datatable process complex response from server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am following this article

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

I have  response from server which I can't change , Now I want to display that data in data table.

I have tried  dataSrc

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

But still not able to show data and count.
Response Format :

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "message":{
         "draw": 1,
         "recordsTotal": 57,
         "recordsFiltered": 57,
         "data":[["data1","test","22-05-2016"],["new enrty"
,"newtag,extra","08-01-2017"],["test","kundan","08-01-2017"],["Ram","kundan","08-01-2017"]["ASDA","ASDAS","11-01-2017"],["ASDASD","ASDAS","11-01-2017"]]
         }}
```

Now I am not able to show it in datatable.

Comment: 1) that's not very complex 2) have you tried to solve this yourself? 3) whats a datatable?

Comment: Which part is required to display in the table  `message.data` ? The other properties look static. Just bind that instead.

Comment: @Searching  If you will check first link u will see that, apart from data, we need other data also ,like draw,recordsTotal..

Comment: @Liam  question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with dataSrc. Given that your data is as you described then this should work:

```
var jsonData = {
    "status": "success",
    "message": {
        "draw": 1,
        "recordsTotal": 57,
        "recordsFiltered": 57,
        "data": [
            ["data1", "test", "22-05-2016"],
            ["new enrty", "newtag,extra", "08-01-2017"],
            ["test", "kundan", "08-01-2017"],
            ["Ram", "kundan", "08-01-2017"],
            ["ASDA", "ASDAS", "11-01-2017"],
            ["ASDASD", "ASDAS", "11-01-2017"]
        ]
    }
};

$(function() {
    var example = $("#example").DataTable({
        //"processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'json',
            "url": '/echo/json/',
            "data": {
                "json": JSON.stringify(jsonData)
            },
            "dataFilter": function(data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                return JSON.stringify(json.message);
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            "title": "Column 1"
        }, {
            "title": "Column 2"
        }, {
            "title": "Column 3"
        }]
    });
});
```

However, your data looks a lot like a server-side call to something that knows how DataTables works... for instance, it has `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered`. Are you perhaps already talking to a server-side which knows how to deal with DataTables?

As an aside, you were missing a comma in your original data. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6s5bn52b/). Hope that helps.

**EDIT** After clarification and some more tweaking this takes the message as the data. Makes use of the [`dataFilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) jQuery ajax callback. Answer and JSFiddle updated.

Comment: Thanks for replay .. This is what I had tried already.. The only problem with this is that , I can't use "draw","recordsTotal " etc , which are must for pagination .. and showing counts ..

Comment: No problem, now I understand your issue. Please check the updated answer, it should do what you require. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarkable  efforts .. using dataFilter fixed it :-)

Comment: May be add a hint that you have to return a string and not JSON in dataFilter callback.

Returning JSON causes issues with the error callback